# how does google voice do this

Tags: android

When you select new message, you have the option to go to google voice, this is also present when you look at something in your inbox and hit reply. How do they do that? I'm talking about the google voice android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the right [tags](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) in your Manifest.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```